# Slower page loading while invoking WebViewClient for the firsttime

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

Below is my code for WebViewClient. I have invoked the class by clicking a button.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if (progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                // Handle the error
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://mylink.com");
        // String customHtml =
        // "<html><body><h1>Hello, WebView</h1></body></html>";
        // webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");

    }

}
```

[image: Error Image]

Its taking more time to load the WebViewClient. I need to speed it up. Any suggestions

Comment: I'm thinking that you are possibly connecting to a slow website? First time load will always be slower as it has not been cached by the browser. If it's your website then you need to look at what you can do to speed up the site.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your code as far as I can see. I would strongly suggest you check out the performance of the web server you are connecting to as this will most likely be the cause of your problems. Particularly look at the servers response times. To test the performance of your web view try setting the url to a fast responding web site, something like google.com.

Answer (score 1):

I think WebView creates a database for all sorts of reasons (like web cache) in your app's temp dir.
This DB is created the first time you call WebView from the app. In subsequent calls it is re-used.

Therefore it is possible that this creation process is what you're experiencing.